# Is there a way to default the 'Folders' section in the vista windows explorer to be collapsed?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

When I open a new windows explorer window, I would like the 'Folders' sections on the left to be collapsed by default, so that the 'Favorite Links' section has maximum room.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way I have found is to create a shortcut to explorer, then edit the target in the shortcut

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,C:\Users\%username%\Links

Sorry it's not exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If your default action for opening a folder is "Open", then Vista will remember your choice of collapsed or open for each type of folder (Documents, Pictures, etc).  If your default action is "Explore" then it always is expanded.

By running explorer.exe, you're defaulting to Explore mode.

The easiest way I can think of is to put a shortcut to C:\ on your quick launch bar, with the default action set to Open, this shortcut will remember your setting whenever you open it.  I'm not sure how you're starting Explorer normally but that's a one click way to do it.

Comment: hmmm interesting. i usually start explorer.exe with the win+e shortcut though.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this to change the default explorer action to "open":

1. Open regedit & navigate to: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell`
2. Double-click the (Default) value on
   the right-hand pane and set its value to "open" (without quotes).